# How does Joomla "force https"?

Tags: ssl, https

I've thought it is done by modifying .htaccess file, but it is not. Making changes to the "force https" option doesn't change the .htaccess file. Can someone explain to me what is the mechanism behind Joomla's "force https" setting in the Global Configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is handled within the `SiteRouter` class in Joomla, more specifically in its `parse()` method where the following condition changes the `scheme` part of the **URI** if `force_ssl` property of the application is set that way and then redirect it:

```
if ($this->app->get('force_ssl') == 2 && strtolower($uri->getScheme()) !== 'https')
    {
        // Forward to https
        $uri->setScheme('https');
        $this->app->redirect((string) $uri, 301);
    }
```

More info on **SiteRouter** class is here:
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Router.SiteRouter.html

Comment: Just for completeness this is indeed what forces a redirect when someone ends up on a http url. The route builder also has logic setup to enforce https connections which is used directly in some components: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/Router/Route.php#L24-L43

Comment: Sample code for user activation which uses this flag https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/45bd91bbfd4523f6971f0a45bd974b231984db7a/components/com_users/models/registration.php#L113-L126